# Returned lines overlap when using ncat pipe in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I am using /bin/sh to write a shell script that fetches data from a telnet call via ncat, like so:

`echo 'transport info' | ncat hostname 9993`

When I do this from a command line the output looks like this:

```
500 connection info:
protocol version: 1.3
model: HyperDeck Studio

208 transport info:
status: record
speed: 0
slot id: 1
clip id: none
display timecode: 00:28:01:27
timecode: 00:00:00:00
video format: 1080i5994
loop: false
```

But when I do it in a shell script `/bin/sh` it looks like this:

```
loop: falseat: 1080i599443:15
```

Here is my sample script:

```
#!/bin/sh
FOO="$( echo "transport info" | ncat -C hostname 9993 )"
echo $FOO
```

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Try `echo "tr in" | ncat -C hyperl1 9993 | dos2unix`. But, not certain that `dos2unix` can read/write from stdin/out, anyone have a man page handy (I don't right now)? Also note that setting vars to multiline output is an advanced topic. You can waste a lot of time getting it right. Until you get everything else working, use tmp files, then work to get it right, saving to a variable. Good luck.

Comment: I don't have `dos2unix`.  I have tried to write to a temp file and then read back, with same results: works on command line, does not work in script.  I have also tried using sed to replace \r with \r\n, etc.  Note, I am on a mac, which is very BSD-like.

Comment: Progress: I installed `dos2unix` using homebrew (`brew install dos2unix`) so now I have that command.  Now, when I use the command line and add a pipe to `dos2unix` I get the same output.  But when I put it in the script, I get it all on one line: `500 connection info: protocol version: 1.3 model: HyperDeck Studio 208 transport info: status: preview speed: 0 slot id: none clip id: none display timecode: 01:10:01:01 timecode: 00:00:00:00 video format: 1080i5994 loop: false`.  Can I break that onto different lines for use with grep?

Comment: `dos2unix` plus sending output to a file and then reading back worked.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that `echo "$FOO"` was necessary for multiline values in a variable. (note the dbl-quotes). Glad you solved your problem! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "transport info" | ncat -C hostname 9993 | dos2unix > /tmp/test.txt
cat /tmp/test.txt
```

Output:

```
500 connection info:
protocol version: 1.3
model: HyperDeck Studio

208 transport info:
status: preview
speed: 0
slot id: none
clip id: none
display timecode: 01:10:01:01
timecode: 00:00:00:00
video format: 1080i5994
loop: false
```